# Using Gitlab Variables in Gitlab README.md for SonarQube Badges

Tags: sonarqube, gitlab, gitlab-ci, badge, readme

I'm using Gitlab and Sonarqube and the [Sonarqube Plugin SVG Badges](http://www.sonarplugins.com/status).
To represent the Sonarqube state on gitlab I have something like this in my `README.md` file:

```
[![coverage](https://sonar.domain.com/api/badges/measure?key=com.domain:projectname&metric=coverage)](https://sonar.domain.com/component_measures/metric/coverage/list?id=de.domain:projectname)
```

This works perfect. My badge is shown, the link is working, everything is fine.

Is there some way to build something like:

```
[![coverage](https://sonar.domain.com/api/badges/measure?key={MYDOMAIN}:{THIS}&metric=coverage)](https://sonar.domain.com/component_measures/metric/coverage/list?id={MYDOMAIN}:{THIS})
```

I want to provide a skeleton that every Developer just can copy and paste into their `README.md` file and the variables are filled into the README automatically, with something like `.gitlab-ci.yml`

I also tried the permanent Gitlab Variables [mentioned here](https://gitlab.com/help/ci/variables/README.md) but that wasn't working too!

```
 [![coverage](https://sonar.domain.com/api/badges/measure?key=com.mydomain:$CI_PROJECT_NAME&metric=coverage)](https://sonar.domain.com/component_measures/metric/coverage/list?id={MYDOMAIN}:$CI_PROJECT_NAME)
```

Anyone has some idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The variables in https://gitlab.com/help/ci/variables/README.md are present only in a CI environment (i.e. a job), so you can't use them in the Markdown viewer when displaying the file. - That's a great idea for a feature proposal, though. I opened one - https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/32255. Feel free to chime in.

What you could do is add a placeholder where you want those variables to go and then create a job which `sed`'s them.

```
update_readme:
  script:
    - echo $CI_PROJECT_NAME # Sanity check
    - sed -ie "s/{THIS}/$CI_PROJECT_NAME/g" README.md
```

Note the use of double-quotes (") and not single quotes ('). Using double-quotes will interpolate `$CI_PROJECT_NAME` while single-quotes would just retain it's literal value.

Comment: but is the `README.me` than really the one I should see? because it's not really changing some content...
so i used something like:
`[![coverage](https://sonar.domain.com/api/badges/measure?key=com.mydomain:${THIS}&metric=coverage)](https://sonar.domain.com/component_measures/metric/coverage/list?id=com.mydomain:${THIS})`

and your script

Comment: a `cat README.md` is showing the correct version aber this is (of course) not showing in the Gitlab

Comment: I marked the question as correct and give you the bounty, because I see that this could be a way to the solution. but still: the `README.md` is of course not replaced in the gitlab. And if i commit it automatically, than the original is gone... so not a good idea. Also with the normal README and a template file, it will still make some confusion for developers, which Readme should be edited... any Idea @Rex ?

Comment: @Joerg you could have a `README_TEMPLATE.md` file, edit the placeholder in that file and output the result into `README.md`. To avoid duplication you can also put a guard clause at the beginning of the script, which ends it if there's already a `README.md` in it.

Comment: The issue on gitlab has unfortunately been automatically closed when they moved everything to the new repo. This seems to be a similar one: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/14389

Comment: This answer almost got me there but you also need to push the result.  See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77610730/9022092

Answer (score 2):

IMPORTANT!

> You should implement a branch/logic to avoid triggering the `.gitlab-ci.yml` in an infinite loop because you are asking to update a repository file from the CI itself

The approach is:

1. Prepare `README.md` with special delimiters around the badge
2. Substitute old/initial badge by `payload` (you should build it, not
   shown here) in the repository loaded `README.md`
3. urlencode the substituted content
4. Update the repository with the Gitlab API

README.md

```
Hello
[//]: # (-- start --)
Initial non working badge
[//]: # (-- end --)
World
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
update_readme:
  script:
  - curl --request PUT --header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: 9koXpg98eAheJpvBs5tK' 'https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/13083/repository/README%2Emd?branch=master&content=$(urlencode "$(sed 's_\[//\]: # (-- end --)_\n&_g;s_\(\[//\]: # (-- start --)\)[^\n]*\n_\1\npayload\n_g' README.md)")&commit_message=update%20file'
```

In `sed` command, substitute `payload` with your actual badge (you should build it, not shown here)

- The solution is to write the `README.md` using the [Update existing file in repository API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#update-existing-file-in-repository)
- The `README.md` should use the special string delimiters that do not appear rendered (they are like hidden comments). These delimiters are always in the file, they do not get substituted. Only what it is in between them get subtituted. This way you can automatically update the badge each time you run the `.gitlab-ci.yml` (only the badge get updated)
- The substitution is done by the `sed` command so you need to add the path to the `README.md`
- The update API needs the `content` to be urlencoded (so the `sed` command is wrapped by a bash `urlencode()` function that should be loaded first (loading not shown):

[urlencode()](https://gist.github.com/cdown/1163649)

```
urlencode() {
    # urlencode <string>
    old_lc_collate=$LC_COLLATE
    LC_COLLATE=C

    local length="${#1}"
    for (( i = 0; i < length; i++ )); do
        local c="${1:i:1}"
        case $c in
            [a-zA-Z0-9.~_-]) printf "$c" ;;
            *) printf '%%%02X' "'$c" ;;
        esac
    done

    LC_COLLATE=$old_lc_collate
}
```

Notes:
The `[//]: # (-- start --)` does not affect the render of your `README.md` so you can use it like hidden comments

Replace your private token with a Gitlab CI `Secret variable`

Comment: this looks pretty nice... I will have a deeper look to it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This creates a new commit everytime