# Link to project's GitLab pages from README

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-pages

I'd like to insert into the `README.md` file a link to the project's GitLab pages URL without hardcoding it.

Something like:

```
Visit the project's [pages site]($PROJECT_NAME_PAGES_URL)
```

instead of

```
Visit the project's [pages site](https://namespace.gitlab.io/project-name)
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, [GitLab-flavored markdown](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html) does not support any variables/substitutions like this. There are some cases where [special gitlab references](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#gitlab-specific-references) are allowed, but the GitLab pages URL is not one of them.

The only workaround might be to have a CI job that parses a readme template and updates the `README.md` on changes, obtaining the pages url from the predefined CI variable `$CI_PAGES_URL` -- something like what is described in [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44022631/5747944).