# How to add issue ID from branch name to merge request description template?

Tags: templates, gitlab, merge-request

By default GitLab adds issue ID from branch name to the merge request description, see [Merge requests to close issues](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/getting_started.html#merge-requests-to-close-issues):

> **Merge requests to close issues**
>
> To create a merge request to close an issue when it’s merged, you can either:
>
> - Add a note in the MR description.
> - In the issue, select **Create a merge request**. Then, you can either:
>
>   - Create a new branch and a draft merge request in one action. The branch is named `issuenumber-title` by default, but you can choose any name, and GitLab verifies that it’s not already in use. The merge request inherits the milestone and labels of the issue, and is set to automatically close the issue when it is merged.
>   - Create a new branch only, with its name starting with the issue number.

But I want to use a custom merge request description template, see [Create a merge request template](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/description_templates.html#create-a-merge-request-template):

> **Create a merge request template**
>
> Similarly to issue templates, create a new Markdown (`.md`) file inside the `.gitlab/merge_request_templates/` directory in your repository. Commit and push to your default branch.

**Research**

- [GitLab Flavored Markdown](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html) doesn't contain any markup for the issue ID from the branch name.
- [Markdown Style Guide for about.GitLab.com](https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/markdown-guide/) doesn't contain any markup for the issue ID from the branch name.
- [GitLab quick actions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/quick_actions.html) doesn't contain any action for the issue ID from the branch name.

**Question**

How to add issue ID from branch name to the merge request description template?

Comment: For now I don't think (or at least I don't know of) there is a built-in feature for that but, GitLab team is working on something that will make this possible. You can follow this [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/18103) and the related issues/MRs...

You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43743141/using-gitlab-variables-in-gitlab-readme-md-for-sonarqube-badges) too.

Comment: @Bosshoss No, I'm still waiting for the issue closed (see Iduoad's comment).

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for a similar problem, i see that Push Options can be a solution for this:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/push_options.html
for example:

```
merge_request.title="<title>" Set the title of the merge request.
merge_request.description="<description>" Set the description of the merge request.
```

It is true that this must be set up by the developer on the client side, but with git hooks and shell scripts, the content can be anything!

Comment: @desertnaut I seriously don't understand what the problem was with my answer. I edited it. That's good?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It would work, but it looks complicated and a little bit error prune.  I hoped, there is some easier solution.